# Elementary OS System Settings has disappeared

Tags: linux, filesystems, elementary-os, settings, restore

I don't know how this happen. Part of the system setting has disappeared.

How have any idea to restore them ?

[image]

Comment: Prefix `sudo` with your command and open system settings.

Comment: Thank you. But I solved this problem, just now.

Comment: That's great. BTW, post your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install switchboard-gnome-control-center
gksu gnome-control-center
```

This will show all settings.
Updated as per Chris's advice.

Comment: You should *never* run X apps with sudo alone, you risk locking yourself out by changing the ownership of key files (notably, the authority files), or having configuration files suddenly become owned by root. Always use `gksudo` or `gksu`, or another tool with similar goals.